# How to get image value of a cell in a datagridview?

Tags: image, datagridview

I want to toggle image in DataGridViewImageColumn on doubleClick, but i can't get the current image value of the cell

```
  DataGridViewImageColumn delCol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
  Image myImage = NewsBarEditor.Properties.Resources.red;
         delCol.Image = myImage;
```

I want to toggle the image to "green" on doubleClick event if current image is red

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Value property of the column rather than Image.

```
delCol.Value = myImage;
```